# AWS Lex slots missing "Slot capture: failure response" option. How can I add this option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm working on a Lex bot someone has created. There are Slots used and I am looking to use Slot capture: failure response but I do not see the option when going to Advanced options.
I have tried this with another Lex bot and the option is there. Can anyone help?
Thank you

I tried creating a new slot and a new intent but the option still isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like the bot was created some time ago and does not have the option
"Slot capture: success response" or "Slot capture: failure response".
I will just create a new bot as the options are there. Thanks